# Can I set the destination of the Text to Columns function as an array?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to split a delimited data set from a source column into an array.  Is this possible?  Reason being that I then want to truncate the data items, remove duplications and count the remaining unique values before writing them into blank columns of my spreadsheet.

Comment: The [Range.TextToColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns) page says that it accepts any valid Range object as the Destination. It only looks at the Top Left cell and auto expands as needed.

Comment: You'll need to use a different method.  Look at the VBA `Split` function; and/or Power Query

Comment: If I would say that you need a piece of code able to return **the count of the unique elements of an array obtained by splitting each cell value by a delimiter**, will it be a correct understanding? I mean to return it on the same row of the processed cell, in the following column.

Comment: @Ron, Split sounds plausible.  Can I read a delimited data set into an array and then use Split?

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes, your understanding is correct (in bold).  However, I also want to write the unique values to the cells in the following columns in the same row.

Comment: OK. I will prepare an answer. It will use only arrays and it will also return the unique string in the following column. At least, in order to easily check if the returned count is correct...

Answer (score 0):

Please, test the next code:

```
Sub CountUniquesElem()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, delim As String
  Dim arr, arrSpl, arrFin, arrS, i As Long
  
  delim = "," 'use any used delimiter (now, comma)
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  arr = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR).Value    'place the range in an array for faster iteration
  ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 2) 'ReDim the final array to keep the processed range
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)                'iterate between the array elements
     arrSpl = Split(arr(i, 1), delim)     'split the content by delimiter
     arrS = Split(UniquesEl(arrSpl), "|") 'split the unique string by "|"
     arrFin(i, 1) = CLng(arrS(0)): arrFin(i, 2) = arrS(1) 'load both columns of the final array
  Next i
  'drop the final array content:
  sh.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 2).Value = arrFin
End Sub

Private Function UniquesEl(ByVal arr) As String
    Dim strCont As String       ' replacing "10" referring to zero indexed as 10th digit
    strCont = Replace("<t><s>" & Join(arr, "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "10", "0")
    arr = WorksheetFunction.FilterXML(strCont, "//s[not(preceding::*=.)]")
    UniquesEl = UBound(arr) & "|" & Join(Application.Transpose(arr), ",")
End Function
```

The above code processes data from "A:A" column, starting from the second row and returns in "B:C".

Please, test it and send some feedback.